# cannot GET after refresh, and error in creating a catch all for server - Express and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have the Error: cannot GET /pathname after refresh. I have seen quite a few articles about it and it all points towards making a catch all for server with /* pointing to index.html. However when I tried it on my server, all i get is 400 bad request. I'm not sure where went wront, and would like some help in debugging. Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI ,{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false})

app.use("/", require("./routes/diseaseRoute"))

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './frontend/public/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
  })



if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    app.use(express.static('frontend/build'))
}

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("express server running on port "+PORT)
})
```

if I take out the app.get the webstie works fine with the refresh error, any leads or help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I though maybe it's becuase my app.use and app.get cannot use the same path, so I moved the app.get into my routes file and changed it into router.route("/").get and now im getting the error message:manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can I know why you added *? I think just ```/``` would do fine If you want to run this controller for all requests.

Comment: I copied this from some articles, i will try removing it and see if it works

Comment: it still doesn't work:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Maybe it's because both app.get and app.use is using ```/``` ?

Comment: I moved the into my routes and turned it into router.route("/").get and now my error message is: manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: controller inside the app.use will work for any method that is get post or any method available we basically use app.use when we have to give a middleware that will work every time regardless of the request method example would be an auth middleware. The reason you are getting 404 because somewhere in you front code you have a manifest.json file which is not available on the server. You might wanna check you frontend code and remove those lines.

Answer (score 0):

change `/*` to `*` and it will work!

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './frontend/public/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
  })
```